# Body text has lost responsiveness

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm running a site on the responsive Sterling WordPress theme (www.bandleandzaeske.com), and I'm having issues with the responsiveness of the body copy. The header and footer of the site are both responsive on mobile and browser-resizing tests, but the body text bleeds into the left and doesn't conform to the resize.

If I change the following "width" definition to 100%, it works fine, but it also pushes the one_third form below the text.

```
.two_thirds {
width:640px !important;
float:right !important;
}
```

Any ideas? Suggestions? I'd be happy to copy more code if that provides more insight.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you always want the form to appear above the text?

Comment: Try using % for the width of both the one_third and two_thirds. Also, if you can add a screenshot of what you want the page to look like it would make helping easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change width to max-width should work:

```
.two_thirds 
{
    max-width:640px !important;
    float:right !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `width: 640px !important;` from the following CSS style in your `index.php` (line 368). (Leave `float:right!important` as it is):

```
.two_thirds {
  // width: 640px !important;
  float: right !important;
}
```

That should fix the issue, as this code is overriding your theme.

Apparently, these styles are generated based on your theme settings, I guess that's where you can change this.